# AWS s3 simultaneous move of the same object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, move

Lately I consider a thing that I haven't totally figured. Basically, the thing is summarized in the question. In a broader way, my question is as follows:

(Assume that these things are done by scripts on different machines or different tasks within the same machine (concurrently))

Assume we have bucket called "bucket-one" and an object in it where the key is "foo/bar.ext"
one task tries to move "foo/bar.ext" to "foo2/bar.ext" and the other tries to move the object to "foo3/bar.txt", and ,say we use boto3 s3 client/resource, for example (probably does not affect the output though).

What happens when you try concurrently move an object **at the exact same time** from a folder to another folder within the same bucket ?

Outputs I have in mind are:

- Both request would succeed with both moving the same file into different folders, so that we have now both "foo2/bar.ext" and "foo3/bar.ext".
- Only one of them is moved either to "foo2/bar.ext" or "foo3/bar.ext"
- Both of the requests failed, object is not moved and retained as "foo/bar.ext".
- All of the above may happen without precisely knowing the output beforehand.

The second question would be the same thing only a change in time **"not at the exact time, but very close (nearly-same time)"**.

I know the odds are not likely at all, but I am curios what it would result in.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible outcome is that you get both destination objects.

S3 doesn't support moving an object to a new key, it only supports making a copy of the object at a new key (whether in the same bucket or a different bucket) and then deleting the original object with a second request.

Deleting an object that is already in the process of being copied or downloaded has no impact on operations that are already in progress on that object.

Additionally, authorized delete operations on recently-deleted objects never fail (this may in fact always be true of delete requests, but this detail isn't important, here) so neither process will be aware that the other process has also just deleted the object when they try, because that operation will succeed.

You don't even need things to occur at the exact same time, in order to end up with two objects.

If the events occur in the order Copy 1, Copy 2, Delete 1, Delete 2, this would still be the outcome, no matter how close in time Copy 1 and Copy 2 occur as long as Delete 1 hasn't prevented Copy 2 from starting... but in fact, delete operations on objects are not themselves instantaneous, so Copy 2 could potentially still work even it starts a brief time period after Delete 1 has already finished.  This is caused by the eventual consistency behavior that S3 provides for delete and overwrite operations, an optimization that trades this consistency for higher performance PUT and GET (including copy). The amount of time for full consistency is not a fixed value and is often close to zero. There is no exposed interface for determining whether a bucket's index replicas are fully consistent.

See [Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

Comment: That "[Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)" link was exactly what I was looking for for further information.